# How to change the launch type of ECS cluster in my Cloudformation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have a Cloudformation template that creates ECS (Fargate) type cluster, service and other mandatory resources. Now I want to change the type of ECS type from Fargate to EC2 launch type. Here is my cloudformation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: The CloudFormation template for the Fargate ECS Cluster.

Parameters:
  Stage:
    Type: String
  ContainerPort:
    Type: Number
  ImageURI:
    Type: String

Resources:

  # Create an ECS Cluster
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'Cluster']]

  # Create a VPC
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties: 
      CidrBlock: 172.10.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: True
      EnableDnsSupport: True

  # Create a Subnet
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.10.1.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::Region", 'a']]

  # Create a Subnet
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 172.10.2.0/24
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Join ['', [!Ref "AWS::Region", 'b']]

  # Create a route table to allow access to internet
  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  # Create a Route to allow access to internet using an internet gateway
  PublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCInternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  # Attach Public Route to SubnetA
  SubnetAPublicRouteAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA

  # Attach Public Route to SubnetB
  SubnetBPublicRouteAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties: 
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB

  # Create an Internet Gateway
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  # Attach the internet gateway to the VPC
  VPCInternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties: 
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  # Create Access Role for ECS-Tasks
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'ExecutionRole']]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'

  # Create a TaskDefinition with container details
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties: 
      Memory: 1024
      Cpu: 512
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - 'FARGATE'
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'Container']]
          Image: !Ref ImageURI
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
              HostPort: !Ref ContainerPort

  # Creat a security group for load balancer and open port 80 in bound from internet
  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'LoadBalancerSecurityGroup']]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  # Creat a security group for Containers and open in bound Container port from Load balancer security group to the Container 
  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'ContainerSecurityGroup']]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          ToPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup

  # Create a LoadBalancer and attach the Security group and Subnets
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'LoadBalancer']]
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
      Subnets: 
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB
      Type: application

  # Create a TargetGroup for HTTP port 80
  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'TargetGroup']]
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  # Create a LoadBalancerListener and attach the TargetGroup and LoadBalancer
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions: 
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  # Create an ECS Service and add created Cluster, TaskDefintion, Subnets, TargetGroup and SecurityGroup
  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: LoadBalancerListener
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'ECSService']]
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 2
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration: 
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          Subnets:
            - !Ref SubnetA
            - !Ref SubnetB
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Join ['-', [!Ref Stage, !Ref 'AWS::AccountId', 'Container']]
          ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
```

Can someone guide what changes I have to made in this template to convert into EC2 type? I am new to cloudformation, I really don't have much idea how to do.
I can't use any other template because this Cloudformation is linked to one more cloudformation stack. Actually I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/aws-cloudformation-managed-complete-ecs-infrastructure-including-ci-cd-pipeline-from-github-to-ecs-b833bb44e01c) and there is Fargate type but I want EC2 launch type.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is the `LaunchType: FARGATE` that needs to be changed to `LaunchType: EC2`.

The second biggest thing is that you would need to add EC2 resources to the cluster to be able to land your tasks (with Fargate you don't need that but if you opt to use the EC2 launch type you have to have a cluster with EC2 instances).

Third you may need to add EC2 to the compatibility section of your task def:

```
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - 'FARGATE'
        - 'EC2'
```

Fourth, assigning public IPs to tasks (`AssignPublicIp: ENABLED`) is not a best practice and it actually won't work with the EC2 launch type (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/13348) for example). You should disable this BUT this means you will need to add a NAT GW to your VPC for your task to be able to go out to the Internet (and grab the container image from ECR). An alternative would be to [add ECR private endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to your VPC to avoid the Internet "long haul".

There may be other things that need tuning but these are the biggest.

PS why do you need to move to EC2 out of curiosity?

Comment: Actually, I have deployed my app using Fargate launch type but it was giving me an error of 502 bad internet gateway. I couldn't find anything through which I can monitor if my docker image is up or not? There is no easy way of troubleshooting while using Fargate. When we use EC2, we can easily go into the machine and find out if our docker container is running or not.

Comment: If you describe the task via the ECS API/console you will see if the task is running. More interesting would be to check the ALB and the target group to see if the task is being registered correctly (I suspect this is where it's breaking - the ALB takes the request but doesn't know where to send it). Your CFN template doesn't show a logging configuration so you won't be able to easily see STDOUT for any possible container misconfiguration but you can [exec into it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) and check inside the container to troubleshoot.

Comment: Crafting a CFN by hand is not the easiest experience. Have you considered using [AWS Copilot](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/overview/)? It's a CLI tool that makes it easy to author/run CFN templates for specific common patterns (e.g. front-end lb web service, batch jobs, etc).

Comment: Can you explain your second point mentioned in the answer? What are required EC2 resources? I haven't found a single document on required resourced to create an EC2 launch type cluster. I have a few templates, but they have added extra resources which is very confusing. There is no proper document that explicitly says these resources are mandatory to create EC2 launch type ECS cluster.

Comment: EC2 resources = EC2 instances. When you launch a task on Fargate you don't need instances connected to your cluster but when you launch a task on EC2 you need instances connected to your cluster. That is what I meant.